# Angular template frozen untill operation complete

Tags: angular

I'm creating a demo application for testing wasm integration with Angular and performance differences between c, c++ and rust languages. I've created 4 sub components, one for each technology tested (javascript is for comparison). I call this components inside app component in this way:

```
<app-wasm-c></app-wasm-c>
<app-wasm-cpp></app-wasm-cpp>
<app-wasm-rust></app-wasm-rust>
<app-javascript></app-javascript>
```

In the app component, when a button is clicked I put calculation settings in a global behaviour subject and each of my component is subscribed to that observable, in this way:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.fibonacciService.params$.subscribe(p=>{
      // do stuff
    });
  }
```

So every component react to changes made into app.component and procede to calculation (in its peculiar way). 
**The problem is that my page remain freezed untill the slowlest computation ends, and after that all 4 divs appears.**

I would do two things:

- display every component independently when its computation ends.
- display a loading during computation (I've tried in different ways but all without success: the template remains frozen during the computation and only in the end the page updates)
- The running application: http://wasm-test.azurewebsites.net/
- The code: https://github.com/zuologio/ng-wasm-benchmark

Comment: Web Worker FTW. You need to execute this function in another execution context.
If this isn't the default with ASM modules.

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded, so you have to do your heavy code in other worker thread

please check this link

https://medium.com/techtrument/multithreading-javascript-46156179cf9a

Comment: I updated the github repository with a working version with web workers... thank you for the hint!